# How to verify method call typsafe in junit with spring?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

how can I replace the `methodName("getEmployeeDetailsById")` with a typesafe expression? Somehow linking directly to the method of the class. Is that possible?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
      mockMvc
        .perform(get("/employee/details/9816"))
        .andExpect(handler().handlerType(EmployeeController.class))
        .andExpect(handler().methodName("getEmployeeDetailsById")); //TODO typesafe?
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your intention, you want build the expectation in static way.

You can use spring [HandlerResultMatchers#methodCall](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/HandlerResultMatchers.html#methodCall-java.lang.Object-) &  [MvcUriComponentsBuilder#on](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#on-java.lang.Class-) to achieve your way, for example:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/details/9816")).andExpect(
  handler().methodCall(on(EmployeeController.class).getEmployeeDetailsById(args))
  // args is any of the arbitrary value just to make the code to compile ---^
)
```

But one thing you need to note is that [MvcUriComponentsBuilder#on](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#on-java.lang.Class-) will [create a proxy to be able to inspect the previous invocations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/155#issuecomment-36487869). when you make the handler method to return a `String` view name, you should make the return type of handler method with its super type (*super interface or superclass*) of the `String` class, since it is **final** and can't be proxied by cglib. for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public Object handlerReturnViewName() {
  //    ^--- use the super type instead
  return "bar";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the method in your Controller which has a @GetMapping annotation (i'm assuming what annotation you use here, adjust as required) with the value of "/employee/details/{id}" by searching for it over all methods in the class:

```
private String findMethodName() {
    List<Method> methods = 
         new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(EmployeeController.class.getMethods());
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
            GetMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
            if(Arrays.asList(annotation.value())
                           .contains("/employee/details/{id}") {
                  return method.getName();
              }
         }
     }
 }
```

Then you can call this method in your mvcTest:

```
.andExpect(handler().methodName(findMethodName()));
```